# Meaning of "draw ire" in a sentence

Tags: idioms

Please, help me to understand what does "**draw ire**" mean in the following phrase:

> Game industry vet draws ire from developers for defense of 80-hour
>   workweeks.

Does it mean that some veteran developer angers other developers, or the opposite - gets their support when he defends 80-hour workweek?

Of course, after reading the whole article, I get some idea, but it would be nice to understand the meaning of the title without reading the whole piece.
(The source: http://www.polygon.com/2016/4/18/11452564/would-you-want-to-work-for-this-guy)

Comment: It's a rather pretentious (mock-formal, dated) usage. Most people in most contexts would use ***attracts [angry] criticism***. [Draw:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/draw) *to bring toward oneself or itself, as by inherent force or influence; attract*, [ire:](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ire?s=t) *intense anger; wrath.* The veteran developer angers other developers ***for = because of*** his support for 80-hour week working (other developers would presumably favour a more manageable 35-hour week).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: thank you for your answer! It is clear and really should be added as one.

Comment: You haven't really explained *why* you had trouble understanding the cited text. I don't think you should have had any trouble finding the relevant definitions of ***draw*** and ***ire*** as given above. Are you really saying that you might have interpreted, say, *John attracted anger from Jack for defending gay marriage* as meaning that John deliberately made Jack angry so that Jack's anger could somehow be used to support the cause of gay marriage?

Comment: The term **draw fire** is much more widely used: in peacetime, the meaning is strictly figurative,

Comment: I don't know if **draw ire** is really dated - [if anything, it's gotten substantially more common in the last 30 years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw+ire&year_start=1900&year_end=2000).  I was surprised to see that [**draw fire** is actually more common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=draw+ire%2Cdraw+fire&year_start=1900&year_end=2000), but it's not exactly the same thing - "draw fire" is kind of a metaphorical usage, whereas "draw ire" is just a collocation: when I think of "VERB ire", the verb is almost always "draw".

Comment: @stangdon, most of the instances of **draw fire** in  your ngram are military (literal): note the peaks corresponding to the two world wars. Even present day usages are mainly war novels. If you  look at **drew fire from/drew ire from**, you get a much fairer comparison- if you check the actual references, most of the occurrences of drew fire are metaphorical. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drew+ire+from%2C+drew+fire+from&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrew%20ire%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrew%20fire%20from%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I don't know exactly why I didn't understand the phrase. Article titles are often confusing (at least for me - I'm not a native speaker). Meaning of "draw ire" was part of it, but also words just "piled up" making it confusing to know who is angry at whom and why. I didn't know how to interpret and wouldn't ask if I did. I had to read title 3 or 4 times before I understood that "vet" means "veteran", then "draw" has many meanings and I've never heard of "draw ire" to know which one to pick. I thought that maybe he is "picturing others to be angry"... thank you for help.

Comment: @stangdon: I didn't really mean the specific collocation was dated - comparatively, it's [so uncommon](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drew+ire%2Cdrew+hostility%2Cdrew+criticism%2Cattracted+ire%2Cattracted+hostility%2Cattracted+criticism&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdrew%20ire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrew%20hostility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdrew%20criticism%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattracted%20hostility%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattracted%20criticism%3B%2Cc0) that wouldn't mean much anyway. But ***ire*** itself has significantly declined over the years.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Draw" used to mean "pull" or "attract".  You still hear it once in a while: you "draw" cards from a deck, a celebrity can "draw" a crowd. Think about the word *drawer*.

"Ire" means anger or irritation.

"Draw ire" is an old-fashioned way to say "get people mad".